# python parallel programming

Tags: python, jobs, subprocess, parallel-processing

hi i need some guidelines how to write programm that executes other python programm but in maximum for example 6 times at once and always try to be 6 process be running even if one ends up

also i would like to know what is happening to those processes right know but i dont want to wait to any process to finish

what is the pid of just created process? and its still running? or there has been an error? or it finish sucessfully?

some job manager ...

```
import subprocess

def start():
    proc = {}
    for i in range (0,6):
        proc[i] = subprocess.Popen(
            ['python', 'someprogramm.py', '--env', 'DEVELOPMENT', '-l'],
            shell = True, 
            stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr = subprocess.STDOUT
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

Comment: i give it a try and it perfectly suites my needs, i recommended it to everyone. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). It sounds like it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with the multiprocessing module, it can handles [pool of worker processes](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocess#using-a-pool-of-workers) that seems similar to what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`poll()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) method to check if a process is still running. You'd have to loop through each process and check if it runs, and otherwise, run a new process.